# open outlook with excel 2010 vba and send email

Tags: vba, excel

In the below excel 2010 `vba` I am trying to send an email if outlook is closed.  I do get the confirmation that the email was sent but nothing gets sent. If outlook is opened there is no problem, but it may not always be.  Thank you :).

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String
Dim oOutlook As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set oOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

If oOutlook Is Nothing Then
    Set oOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If


strbody = "Hi xxxx," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "There are 4 reports ready" & vbNewLine & _
          "Regards" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "xxxxx xxxxx"

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = "xxxxx@xxxxxxx.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "data"
    .Body = strbody
    '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
    .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

' Confirm that the email(s) has/have been sent
    MsgBox "The data has been emailed sucessfully.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: "I do get the confirmation that the email was sent but nothing gets sent." The problem is the second "On Error Resume Next". Keep in mind such code is for non-programmer users not for you, the developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code opens outlook...

```
Application.ActivateMicrosoftApp xlMicrosoftMail
Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a different test. Err.Number is likely 429 ActiveX component can't create object.

```
On Error Resume Next
Set oOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set oOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If
```

Maybe this:

```
Set oOutlook = Nothing

On Error Resume Next
Set oOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

If oOutlook Is Nothing Then
    Set oOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If
```